# Not able to install Apps to Tizen TV emulator

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-sdk, tizen-tv

I am using the Tizen SDK IDE version 2.4.0_Rev5 and the Tizen TV emulator Package version 2.2.92.
I am able to successfully start the emulator but I am not able to install apps from my Laptop(Tizen IDE) to the emulator.
I get the following error:

*step SDB shell handle failed
Failed to step SDB shell handle '2 mkdir /tmp UserX' command
 operation
(Return Code:31)sdb command rejected exception*

I have created the certificates(author and distributor certificates) and selected "Permit to install applications" for the emulator under the connection explorer in the IDE.

I have actually successfully installed the same IDE and emulator on another PC where I am able to install and run the apps. I followed the same process on this PC, however I get the error mentioned above

Host PC:
Dell Inspiron i5

Windows 10 64-bit

JRE: 1.8.0_51

JDK: 1.7.0_45

[image: SDB capability]
[image: Emulator Configuration]

Comment: Hello. You may want to add host PC details (OS, Java version, etc) and emulator (skin, RAM, tuner, etc) details.

Comment: I have added some more details

Comment: @ArchitSinha - You should probably log a 1:1 Q&A for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Tizen Web project should be created from the template TV-(**latest version**)-Basic application(or else).

Try creating a new Tizen Web project from the correct template and assign/copy the required files to that project.

You may check sdb capability of the device.

a) Run cmd/terminal

b) Move to [SDK install Folder]\tools

c) Run command 'sdb capability' .

[image]

If you cannot see capability value of sdb, try updating your TV device software.

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the question with some additional details (including "sdb capability command").
The templates which I used for creating the projects are "TV-2.4" and "TV-Samsung-Public-2.4". I see the same issue with both.